# How to tell pip to install test dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

We are using `pip -e .` to install our package in editable/development mode, instead of using `python setup.py develop`. (We have to do so, because we pull packages from the public PyPi server and a private one. This did not worked for us using `python setup.py develop`.)

But `pip -e .` does not install test dependencies and I could not find some flag to force it to do so. How do I install test dependencies using pip?

Comment: Have you tried `python setup.py test`? If properly set up, this will install test-specific dependencies and run all tests.

Comment: For anyone only coming across this question now, please see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870629/pip-install-test-dependencies-for-tox-from-setup-py#comment122181805_29870629) on the recent deprecation of `tests_require`.

Answer (score 6):

I use `extra_require` in the setup.py as specified [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies). For example:

```
setup(
    name="Project-A",
    ...
    extras_require={
        'develop':  ["mock==2.0.0"],
    }
)
```

And to execute it using `pip install`:

```
pip install -e .[develop]
```

Or as suggested below the expanded version:

```
python -m pip install --editable '.[develop]'
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming later with `zsh` as their default shell this may save you some grief.

Turns out zsh interprets the dot as a special character so this won't work:

```bash
python -m pip install --editable .[develop]
```

You need to quote the extras like so:

```bash
python -m pip install --editable '.[develop]'
```