# pip install test dependencies for tox from setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, easy-install, tox

I made my project with `setuptools` and I want to test it with `tox`. I listed dependencies in a variable and added to `setup()` parameter (`tests_require` and `extras_require`).  My project needs to install all of the dependencies listed in `tests_require` to test but `pip install` is not installing them.

I tried this but it did not work:

```
install_command = pip install {opts} {packages}[tests]
```

How can I install test dependencies without having to manage multiple dependency lists (i.e. Having all dependencies listed in both `test_requirements.txt` and the `tests_require` variable)?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can - all of the projects I've seen with `tox` integration just have a specific test requirements file and set `deps = -r whatever_file.txt` in `tox.ini`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe just I want to make no deps text file. If I make it, I must manage two deps list.

Comment: Yes, I understand why you don't want to do it, and I'm telling you that *I'm not sure you can avoid it*. The other option is to read in your test dependencies from the file in `setup.py` rather than hard-coding them; that takes you back to a single DRY list.

Comment: For anyone coming across this question now: As of 2021, `setup.py test` and `tests_require` are now deprecated ([issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1684), [docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies)). So the answers involving `extras` below are no longer just workarounds but the only official non-deprecated way of implementing test-only dependencies.

Answer (score 65):

I've achieved this by committing a slight abuse of [extra requirements](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies). You were almost there trying the extras syntax, just that `tests_require` deps aren't automatically available that way.

With a `setup.py` like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

test_deps = [
    'coverage',
    'pytest',
]
extras = {
    'test': test_deps,
}

setup(
    # Other metadata...
    tests_require=test_deps,
    extras_require=extras,
)
```

You can then get the test dependencies installed with the extras syntax, e.g. from the project root directory:

```
$ pip install .[test]
```

Give that same syntax to Tox in `tox.ini`, no need to adjust the default `install_command`:

```
[testenv]
commands = {posargs:pytest}
deps = .[test]
```

Now you don't need to maintain the dependency list in two places, and they're expressed where they should be for a published package: in the packaging metadata instead of `requirements.txt` files.

It seems this little extras hack [is not all that uncommon](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2009/12/17/managing-dependencies.html).

Comment: It seems this does not just install the dependencies, but also the current project.

Comment: @tkruse Yes, that is inherently what `pip install .` does with or without the `[extras]` syntax. I typically find that inconsequential as I'm normally developing in a virtualenv, and even beneficial because your tests can use module imports for your code under test and help catch that you don't have relative import issues, etc. @Guy Gangemi raises a caveat in his answer that may be a valid one, but it's not a scenario I've encountered in practice personally. His answer, based on a newer feature of Tox, may be a good one—I don't want to opine on the setuptools `python setup.py test` debate.

Answer (score 17):

### Solution

Tox 2.6 introduced [`extras`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-extras) option. This will install `extras` from the sdist it just built, only for that sdist and at the time it was doing the normal sdist install.

setup.py should look like:

```
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    extras_require={
        'tests': ['pytest>=3.7.0', 'more_packages'],
    },
    ...
 )
```

tox.ini should look like:

```
[testenv]
...
extras = tests
...
```

### Concerns

Other approaches may get similar results but introduce unnecessary risk and limits the usefulness of other features:

`deps =.[tests]` is a bit of a hack. The field is for packages the environment needs. If setup.py install_requires references another package you develop, you could use it to pull in a pre-release version of it. As shown, it will install your whole package from your working directory (whatever state that is in!) just to get at the list of packages in `tests`. `install_command` will run next, installing your newly minted sdist. In short, issues with the sdist may be masked since you already have installed from your working copy.

Editing `install_command` is overkill. It'll overwrite items installed via `deps`. (again maybe you used it to install a specific version of a package).

`tests_require` is used when `python setup.py test` is run. [Tox](https://tox.wiki/en/3.27.1/example/basic.html#integration-with-setup-py-test-command) recommends avoiding `python setup.py test` so you can ignore `tests_require` all together.

Comment: If `python setup.py test` is discouraged and so is `pip install .[test]` then what is the utility of defining these tests as a `setuptools` extra at all? Shouldn't we just keep the Tox definition completely separate from `setup.py`?

Comment: @RobinWinslow we agree. `pip install <package>[test]` installs packages for running tests probably though pytest or the likes. A user has the option of running your tests in the environment they intend to run your package in. It should work independently of Tox. A dev uses Tox to run those tests under multiple environments and the example `.ini` shown is the best way to make that `pip install` call with minimal side effects.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is have a single file (called `test_requirements.txt`) and list out the test dependencies like so:

```
dnspython==1.12.0
easydev==0.8.3
enum34==1.0.4
fabric==1.10.1
...
```

Then, in `setup.py`, parse and store the file contents in a list and pass that list to `setup`:

```
tests_require = [line.strip() for line in 
                 open('test_requirements.txt')
                 if line.strip() and not line.strip().startswith('--')]

setuptools.setup(
    ...
    tests_require=tests_require,
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the following command, Tox will install your `test_requires` before running the tests:

```
commands = {envpython} setup.py test
```

You'll also need to [add to setup.py](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) where are the tests with this:

```
test_suite="tests_module"
```

Finally, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37033551/3339058)'s an answer for a similar question with a nice example.